# Installing gcc manually redhat

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am working on a system on which I am a non-root user.

While trying to install gcc 5.1 in a custom directory as the present shared version of gcc isn't working for postgresql installation, I started out by 
wget [gcc 5.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html).

After unzipping the folder, ran the commands below:

```
  cd /seq/genome_portal/lib  
  mkdir bld
  mkdir gcc
  cd bld
  /seq/genome_portal/lib/gcc-5.1/configure --prefix=/seq/genome_portal/lib/gcc
```

However config.log still shows this error:

```
/../../redhat_6_x86_64/pkgs/gcc_4.9.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.0/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The prerequisites that come after

```
./contrib/download_prerequisites
```

are gmp,mpfr and mpc. I started with gmp and ended up in the same error as above. I somehow need to tell these programs that I do not want to use the existing gcc.

But I get the same error as mentioned before. Any advice as to how I can proceed to install it?

Comment: Install the [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) package on your system (or ask you admin to do that). If it's already installed, you might have to expand your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

Comment: I tried installing MPFR, but while configuring this package I get the same error as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Have you considered installing an [rpm as user](http://superuser.com/questions/209808/how-can-i-install-an-rpm-without-being-root), instead of building code from scratch?

Comment: This only extracts, I will still need to install after that right?

Comment: It should extract the libs and everything into a dedicated folder. You have to expand your paths to those folders. What I do is using a `~/opt/` folder where I install local packages, and have `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and others expand to `~/opt/bin`, `~/opt/lib` etc.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Building a compiler is much more complicated that building a straightforward utility; just running `configure` is not enough.

Primarily, you need to read the instructions; they are provided in the GCC source directory in the `INSTALL` subdirectory.  They are in HTML so point your browser at it.

I know you didn't do this yet because the step on configuration makes very clear you should be using an out-of-source configuration; e.g., something like:

```
mkdir ../bld
cd ../bld
../gcc-5.1/configure ...
```

rather than running `./configure`.

Regarding the missing dependencies, there's a "prerequisites" section in the docs.  To get MPFR and other helpful things you can run:

```
cd gcc-5.1
./contrib/download_prerequisites
```

ETA: This should work:

```
rm -rf newgcc
mkdir newgcc
cd newgcc
tar xzf gcc-5.1.tar.gz
cd gcc-5.1
./contrib/download_prerequisites
mkdir ../bld
cd ../bld
../gcc-5.1/configure <configopts>
make -j8
make install
```

(or whatever `-j` you prefer).

Comment: get the same error. need to bypass the existing gcc on the system.

Comment: You don't build those libraries yourself.  You just run the script, which will download those prerequisites and unpack them so the are placed correctly in the GCC source tree.  Then when you run the configure and build it will notice those directories and compile those extra libraries at the proper times using the new compiler, etc.